# Is it possible to merge a content folder into a single html file

Tags: html, image, merge, subdirectory

I have a content folder for a navigable website, or webapp, the folder looks likes this:

**[contents of the Content Folder]**

[image]

This folder contains assets, images, text and other html files as well as sub folders.

I was wondering if it was in anyway possible to merge this folder into a single file, preferably html, and if so, what tools can I use to do it.

Sort of, "converting" the folder into a html file, that when clicked, would perform the same function as index.html (Basically, open the home web page from where someone can navigate the site)

I tried a tool called html merge but it didn't work out, and other search results just showed instructions for merging html files.

Thank you!

Comment: @ObsidianAge I understand there's probably no real need. I'm trying to make a project easier to run and wanted to experiment with this option.

Comment: Well you could create a single HTML file, use inline styles and scripts...  and even use Base64 encoding to negate the need for external images. However, this would make a rather 'unmanageable' HTML file. What if you want to modify an image at a later stage? It would be much easier if it was external. Especially if you have multiple pages referencing the same image. I'd definitely recommend keeping things the way you have them now - it's much easier to maintain.

Comment: @ObsidianAge okay, my main goal was to simplify things further but you make a good argument. I'll probably just leave things as they are. Thank you :D

Comment: Though there is an appropriate answer below, I don't see why this question was "closed" on the grounds of needing to be more "focused". The author had a very specific question, and explained it precisely. What's more, there's an appropriate answer included, but there's no room for further discussion, comments, or updated solutions. I had this exact same question myself...I wanted to combine a parent html file and its associated directory into a single file because my reference management software (Zotero) was having trouble displaying the separated documents.

Comment: @graggsd It's been a spell, but any chance you remember what the answer said?  The question has been reopened but there are no answers below.

Comment: I reccomend you not to merge all the files as it makes it easier for the website to load correctly, just leave it as it is now.